# Convert a function value into a string?

Tags: php

I have added `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'blog/wp-load.php';`

to my website in order to display the latest blog posts to the footer of my custom php built website.

However this has tripled the resources used by my server which is causing issues with my server due to traffic that my website is getting particularly from search engine spiders.

To get around this, I want to include this file to a cronjob file which will insert the last 5 blog posts into a new mysql table (before emptying the table completely) and remove wp-load.php from my website.

However I am having issues with inserting the urls / titles into my mysql table from a function.

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5 // Specify how many posts you'd like to retrieve
);
$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $latest_posts->the_post();      

class url {
    public function __toString() {
      the_permalink();
    }
}

$url = strval(new url);

class title {
    public function __toString() {
        echo the_title();
    }
}

$title = strval(new title);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO latestblogposts (`url`, `title`) VALUES (?,?);");
    $stmt->execute([$url, $title]);
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of the the_permalink(); function

```
    function the_permalink( $post = 0 ) {
18          /**
19           * Filters the display of the permalink for the current post.
20           *
21           * @since 1.5.0
22           * @since 4.4.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
23           *
24           * @param string      $permalink The permalink for the current post.
25           * @param int|WP_Post $post      Post ID, WP_Post object, or 0. Default 0.
26           */
27          echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post ), $post ) );
28  }
```

How can I convert this to a string so I can insert the contents into mysql?

Comment: why not just query the table directly, then what ever WP rubbish is hurting the load wont be an issue

Comment: Hi rtfm, wordpress has a really strange way of storing post data, mixing footers, headers, login pages and among blog posts. However after quite a bit of playing around I managed to build a query that seems to exclude all of that and include category slugs etc which I will post for others to use. I wasn't going to give it ago until you posted about it as it seemed fairly difficult so thanks :)

Comment: How about using some cache, such as memcache or redis?

Comment: Thanks Cemal, I am using memcache, varnish as well as 24 hour caching on cloudflare, however I am getting around 15,000 pages spidered every single day by googlebot not to mention other search engines which is where issues are starting to crop up :) 

I was really suprised at how much additional load this wordpress file adds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built an alternative method which will query the wordpress table, exclude all post data aside from actual blog posts and add the slug information to build a complete url.

Posting below for others to use, however still curious if my original question is achievable at all :)

```
    select post_name, post_title, slug from wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id)

where post_status = 'publish' and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY post_name
ORDER BY `post_date`DESC LIMIT 3
```

As you can see from my new relic logs below, I removed this at around 1.45pm. Removing this file has a big impact on performance. [image: New Relic]